# Passing data from PHP array to Highcharts chart with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to draw a highcharts chart that comes from my sql database which i am querying with getdata.php?id=allTemp. I don't really know about JSON that much but I have assembled the code below so far, and the chart does not even draw. the $.getJSON function works when I get a single variable such as weather.wesleyweisenberger.com/getdata.php?id=humidity, but as soon as I try to fetch getdata.php?id=allTemp it does not work, please help me...

```
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
                    }
```

and the return is in the format

```
{"timestamp":"2018-05-30 00:33:05","temperature":"67.39","humidity":"66.57","pressure":"99.21"}{"timestamp":"2018-05-30 00:47:39","temperature":"65.52","humidity":"70.41","pressure":"99.2"}{...
```

My index.php file reads:

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $.getJSON('getdata.php?id=allTemp', function(json){
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    series: [{
                        data: json
                    }],
                    title: {
                        text: 'Title'
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: That's invalid json.  Push all the $data to an array, and echo that array encoded at the very end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{...}{...}{...}
```

That is an invalid json pattern.  You are getting this because you are echoing multiple json objects, where the responses expects a single one.  You can correct this by only echoing once.

```
$results = array();
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($results, $data);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Highchart uses arrays to fill its data, and you are just returning a lot of objects side by side, with no actual acceptable format, now with the code bellow, you will print an array of objects stringified.

Try this on your PHP:

```
var $stringToReturn = [];

while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  push($stringToReturn, $data);
}

echo json_encode($stringToReturn);
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully! Do you know how I can assign different parts of the json array to each axis in highcharts, such as assigning the timestamps to the xAxis and temperature to the yAxis?

Comment: Yes, check the Highcharts documentation, it's really complete with a bunch examples too: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes